# Pantheon Files doesnt show thumbnails for images in Freya

Tags: release-freya, pantheon-files

I don't get any image previews in Pantheon Files.

I already did the chown of the .thumbnails folder as suggested in various other places, but that didn't help. The thing is: I do get previews for PDFs and Fonts. I also tried the following: I put the tumbler.rc from /etc/xdg/tumber into ~/.config/tumbler and set PDF disabled to true, with the effect that there were in fact no PDF thumbnails generated anymore. So somehow tumbler does work, and even reads the tumbler.rc correctly and can write to the .thumbnails folder. Just not for image previews (not JPG nor PNG etc.).

I am by far no linux expert, so I am pretty much stuck now how to proceed.

Btw, on my laptop everything works fine, just not on my workstation. I did update, upgrade, dist-upgrade etc. on both of them.

Edit: Just saw that I also get previews for BMPs.

Comment: Just made a new observation:
Once I edit the name of a PNG in Files, I do get the preview. I suppose that hints at some rights or ownership crap? Any ideas for what I should look out for?

Comment: I would like to add to this problem that the thumbnails work perfectly fine when using nautilus. I also tried with uninstalling and reinstalling tumbler-plugins-extra as well as pantheon-files. Still no success. What else can I try?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using Freya stable version (Files r1980)?  Do the thumbnails show if you press the reload button?

One thing that can stop thumbnailing working (at all) is if you show a folder containing a .webm file; this seems to cause tumblerd to hang.  The latest version of Files does not suffer from this as it uses a newer version of tumbler. (see bug 1532512).  To escape from this navigate away from the offending folder, kill the tumblerd then reload the folder (without .webm file).

Also, Files will not thumbnail files situated on a network folder.

However, using r1980 version I do not have any trouble with thumbnailing jpg files in a local folder (without .webm).

Comment: Hey! Yep, I have updated and upgraded everything, pantheon-files is at 0.2.4.
Reloading does not help, I do not have any .webm files whatsoever, and it also does not work on local drives. 

I can make files show the thumbnails if I edit the name of a file. But as soon as I reload the folder the thumbnail goes away...

Comment: Oh, and I also do get previews for BMPs, TGAs, even JP2s.
And what's even weirder: When I rename a .JPG to .TGA, it shows the thumbnail, even when I reload the folder it still works.

Comment: I will have to install a completely vanilla version of Freya to check this out, as I do development and have the daily repositories installed, so I probably have later versions of some libraries even when running r1980 of Files.  e.g. my tumbler version is 0.1.30

Comment: Thanks so much for looking into this!
Thing is, it works fine on my other computer, so most likely it is something I have done on this system, which causes the error. I just have no clue how to search for this error. For example, could it be issues with some image format libraries?
Btw, I have also this version of tumbler installed: tumbler 0.1.30-1ubuntu1

Comment: after using Freya for quite sometime, then I stumbled this issue, any news or workaround to fix this?

Comment: I have investigated a little further and the problem seems to occur when a file has never been thumbnailed before.  Once it has been thumbnailed (e,g, by pressing reload) it never reoccurs.  So it looks like a bug in Files which I (or someone) will try to fix soon.

Comment: I reinstalled Freya from scratch, on a new system, and everything worked fine. Thumbnails were generated as expected. Until today :D
Something must have messed up the system. Could be because of some libaries that I installed in order to compile Blender? One thing I did yesterday was this:  sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx

After that I wanted to reboot. lightdm wasnt starting, so I installed the nvidia driver again, which fixed the problem. But now thumbnails are missing again. The other thing I did was to install The eye of Gnome, Synapse and gThumb. Uninstalling didnt help.

Comment: The bug affecting the the thumbnailing of files for the first time seems to be a regression in the development branch - I could not reproduce after a vanilla install of Freya (Files version 0.2.4 r1980).  So it should only affect Freya users if they also have the development ppa installed (a fix is in the pipeline).  The problem experienced by sebastia_k sounds like a library incompatability problem of some kind - Files relies on tumbler and dbus to supply the thumbnails. After a clean install this is version 0.1.30 of tumbler and version 1.16.18 if dbus.

Comment: Try monitoring dbus messages from the thumbnailer with dbus-monitor sender=org.freedesktop.thumbnails.Thumbnailer1.  When Files shows a view containing images for which no thumbnail exists (in ~/.thumbnails/normal then messages concerning this file should be exchanged with the system thumbnailer (and thumbnails appear in the ~/.thumbnails/normal, which Files displays).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, @JeremyWootten, however it still is weird. I checked the versions, and tumbler is at 0.1.30 and dbus at 1.6.18, so looks fine? I also tried using the command you suggested as followed: I have a Files window open with 1 JPG. In terminal I do "dbus-monitor sender=org.freedesktop.thumbnails.Thumbnailer1". No mention about the image in the message. However, when I rename the file, stuff starts to happen. See this screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ojqqvl0hpi94upx/thumbnail-bug.png?dl=0

Comment: @sebastian_k: You need to start monitoring dbus before you open Files otherwise you will miss any messages sent when the view is first displayed. But it is weird. I can only suggest installing Freya again (in another partition if you do not want to lose your current install) then make any changes one at a time, checking Files between each change to pin-point what is causing it.

Comment: Small update: What I've done so far is to install eOS to a virtual machine and do all the things I mentioned above (install EoG, Blender buildfiles etc.), but I cannot reproduce the bug. It's so weird! And having thumbnails is rather important to my workflow :(

Comment: Are you trying to clean the thumbnails cache? I use the command `rm -r ~/.thumbnails`. Close Pantheon-files and access again the folder that you want to create new thumbnails.

Comment: I already tried that, without success. 
Btw., it's now the third time I installed eOS from scratch. After a few weeks where everything went smooth, all of a sudden thumbnails are gone again. But without me doing anything fancy. I really have no clue what this is...